# jquery - enabling a button is confusing

Tags: jquery

I always try to do this `$("input[name=button]").attr("disabled", '');` and it doesn't work. Why does this not work?

I ended up using this `$("input[name=button]").attr("disabled", false);`. Seems to me that both are equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does this not work?

`disabled` is a so called [*boolean attribute*](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute):

> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

So an empty value still indicates the presence of the attribute and therefore the form element stays disabled.

---

> Seems to me that both are equivalent.

They are not. jQuery treats boolean attributes differently. It tests the value of the new, uhm, value, and [removes the attribute if the value is `false`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8.2/src/attributes.js#L492):

```
set: function( elem, value, name ) {
    var propName;
    if ( value === false ) {
        // Remove boolean attributes when set to false
        jQuery.removeAttr( elem, name );
    } else {
        // ...
    }
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) to remove an attributes

For removing `disabled`, try doing this,

`$("input[name=button]").removeAttr("disabled");`

Answer (score 2):

`disabled` is a property and you should use `prop` method instead of `attr` method:

```
$("input[name=button]").prop("disabled", false);
```

> The `.prop()` method is a convenient way to set the value of properties—especially when setting multiple properties, using values returned by a function, or setting values on multiple elements at once. It should be used when setting selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked, or defaultSelected. Since jQuery 1.6, these properties can no longer be set with the `.attr()` method. They do not have corresponding attributes and are only properties.

Comment: How come this `$("input[name=button]").prop("disabled", '');`  works? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kHTGQ/1/)

Comment: @bhb: `.prop` sets the **property** of the DOM element (`.attr` sets the HTML attribute). The empty string is implicitly converted to a boolean, so you are essentially doing `element.disabled = false;`, which works as expected. There is a difference between between properties and attributes.

Comment: `''` is a falsy value in JS, as `''` is a falsy value, in your code `disabled` property is set to `false`. As Felix mentions there is a difference between a property and an attribute.